# Stuck with Simple Html Dom and extracting information

Tags: html, dom, parsing

I'm trying to use simple html DOM to extract everything inside a tag with the class "sitepoint". Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('examplewebsite');
$ret = $html->find('.sitepoint');
echo $ret;

?>
```

Below is an example of one of the sitepoint tags (there are ten or so) with the information inside which I want.

```
<dl class="sitepoint">
<dd class="thumbnail">
<a href="blabla" ></a><a href="/toolbar/sidepanel.php?url=random.html" >Get This      Now</a>   </dd><dt class="notext"><a href="/to/" >Title</a></dt><dd class="starts">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td class="textUncolor"> CUT OUT SOME IMAGES AND       ADDRESSES HERE
                            </td></tr>
</table>
</dd>
```

Can anyone help me get it working?

Comment: +1 for not trying to use a regex. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the outertext attribute.

```
 $html->find('.sitepoint',0)->outertext;
```

Check the [docs](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more info. Look under "magic attributes"

**EDIT**

When selecting classes, you need to specify which one in the document you use. I've changed the above example to reflect this. This is tested and works. (notice the 0 as the second parameter to find)

Comment: Hello, I changed the line to

    $html->find('.sitepoint')->outertext;

and it didn't work.

Comment: does the html close the <dl> tag?

Comment: Ah I must have left the </dl> tag out, it's closed in the html.

Btw there are several <dl></dl> tags in the document.

Would appreciate if someone could tell me where I am going wrong here.